# "%" symbol in an NSLocalizedString

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring

I have the following line of code:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", nil),80.1]);
```

The 80.1 is a float that is being inserted into the localized string. This works fine. However I want a % symbol in the localized string. I have tried using %%, but it does not output the % symbol - instead it outputs a space, the numbers 5302 and also removes part of the string that precedes the %% characters.

How can I add a % symbol to a string returned by NSLocalizedString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is not with the `NSLocalizedString`, but with `NSLog`'s interpretation of `%` symbol. If you pass a format string to `NSLog`, and put the string that you would like to show as an object parameter, the percentage sign `%` should survive:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", nil),80.1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: The first argument for NSLog is a format string. You've got a format string, so you should pass it to NSLog:

```
NSLog (NSLocalizedString (@"KEY", nil), 80.1);
```